# In extjs How to change URL to set city name dynamically

Tags: url, extjs4, weather

I am working in extjs. I am working on finding of weather information functionality of given city. So in extjs4 controller i have code as-

```
getWeather : function() {
        $obj = 'pune';
        Ext.require('Ext.data.JsonP', function() {
            Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/pune.json",
                success : function(parsed_json) {
                    var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                    var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
                    alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: "
                            + temp_c);
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

Its working correctly. But in the above function i want to set city name dynamically. suppose i have variable $cityname=pune.Then using this variable how i need to modify URL-"http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/pune.json" so that if weather information will be get retrieved depending upon city name that variable has. So how to change URL to set city names dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the params object passed to the request method:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-method-request

example:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
     url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/..",
     success : function(response) { ...},
     params:{foo:'bar'}
});
```